# PostgreSQL. How to concatenate two strings value without duplicates

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have two strings as below:

```
_var_1 text := '815 PAADLEY ROAD PL';
_var_2 text := 'PAADLEY ROAD PL';
_var_3 text;
```

I want to merge these two strings into one string and to remove duplicates:

```
_var_3 := _var_1 || _var_2;
```

As a result, the variable (_var_3) should contain only - `815 PAADLEY ROAD PL` without dublicate.
Can you advise or help recommend any PostgreSQL feature?

I read the documentation and could not find the necessary string function to solve this problem... I am trying to use `regexp_split_to_table` but nothing is working.

I tried to use this method, but it's not what I need and the words in the output are mixed up::

```
WITH ts AS (
    SELECT
        unnest(
            string_to_array('815 PAADLEY ROAD PL PAADLEY ROAD PL', ' ')
        ) f
)
SELECT
    f
FROM ts
GROUP BY f

-- f
-- 815
-- ROAD
-- PL
-- PAADLEY
```

Comment: For this particular format you can do replace(var1,var2,'') || var2 but I can't tell if that will cover all your needs.

Comment: How do you detect duplication? You could do something like `_var_3 text := _var_1 || CASE WHEN _var_1 like '%' || _var_2 THEN '' ELSE _var_2 END;` so that if `_var_1` ends with the full text of `_var_2` it doesn't get concatenated. However, you will need more complicated regex (instead of the `like`) if you need to handle more complicated matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to treat strings as word lists and then you have to concat them like they were a sets to be unioned, with retaining order. This is basically done by following SQL:

```
with splitted (val, input_number, word_number) as (
  select v, 1, i
  from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('815 PAADLEY 2 ROAD 3 PL',' ')) with ordinality as t(v,i)
  union
  select v, 2, i
  from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('PAADLEY ROAD 4 PL',' ')) with ordinality as t(v,i)
), numbered as (
  select val, input_number, word_number, row_number() over (partition by val order by input_number, word_number) as rn
  from splitted
)
select string_agg(val,' ' order by input_number, word_number)
from numbered
where rn = 1
```

| string_agg |
| --- |
| 815 PAADLEY 2 ROAD 3 PL 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aXBeRXOL)

However this is not kind of task to be solved in SQL in smart and elegant way. Moreover, it is not clear from your specification what to do with duplicate words or if you want to process multiple input pairs (both requirements would be possible, though SQL is probably not the right tool). At least please provide more sample inputs with expected outputs.

Comment: I have initial data from an external source, and as it turns out, my fields (some rows) have data inside `field_1`, such as `field 2` + `field 3`. I'm trying to clear the data and create one field, it will combine information from these three:
`field_1, field_2, field_3

167 KAMAM PL, 167, KAMAM PL;

87, 341, LL MOL ALLEY;

786 5th AVENUE, 786, 5th AVENUE;
APAT 3, 7651, 3th ROAD;
,12581, 1th ROAD;`

I think your answer can help me!

Comment: ok, if the input values are represented as two columns in table with multiple rows then you will probably have to `lateral join` the result of `regexp_split_to_array` to that table and then `partition by` not only the `val` column but also by row identifier.